# struts 2 package names

Tags: struts2

In struts 2, if we have action declaration as :

```
<package name="pdfReports" namespace="/reportPdfs" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" .......
```

What should be the action url corresponding to this?
This url:

```
/reportPdfsreports/12-008975/someActionName.action
```

is giving error:

```
There is no Action mapped for action name someActionName
```

Comment: Please revise your question to explain what you are trying to achieve with your URLs. What is the relevance of the word 'reports' after the namespace? What is the significance of 12-008975?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL would be `/reportPdfs/someActionName.action`